# Switch Magento store if country changes

Tags: magento2.3, price, multistore, shipping-address

I have a website i want to set the price of **Product A** as Rs 10 (fs shipping address is India) and  Rs 15 (if the shipping address is outside India)

I want that during checkout if the user selects country price gets changed based on his country.

for that

```
1: I have created two stores Store India and STore Outside India 
2: price attribute scope changed to store level
3: I do not want to restrict country for store instead it should auto switch
```

based on the shipping country

what should I do to achieve above please help

Comment: So based on the country selection, you want to change price of the product which added to the cart?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes based on customer shipping address

Comment: I saw you post for this task, just wanted to highlight this is a very wrong approach. you don't need multiple stores. what you need is segmentation (already exists for commerce), you can use groups if you are in community and handle the assignment of customers in groups according to their countries, you can add a promotion with specific discounts based on the country (again if it fits the need and maybe you need to customise for the conditions to include the customer), there are too many solutions without duplicating store and messing the price attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach, you don't need multiple stores what you need is segmentation (already exists for commerce), you can use groups if you are using community and customise the assignment of customers in groups according to their countries, you can add a promotion with specific discounts based on skus and the country (again if it fits the need and maybe you need to customise for the conditions to include the customer), there are too many solutions without duplicating store and messing the OOTB price attribute.

Comment: can you help me with possible approach

Comment: which of the suggested approaches fit more what you need? you can simply use the customer groups and the special price per group?

Comment: @laurent when i change a country how i change price per group ?

Comment: additional development needed so the group should be changed on country change but this solution might work only for registered customers. so it depends on what you want, maybe the easiest is to define the country context in the cart promotions conditions and set the product sku(s) discounts for some countries ?

Answer (score 0):

As laurent already mentioned multiple stores or storeviews are the wrong approach for your issue. The easiest and fastest way would be a 3rd party extension like the `Magento 2 Customer Segmentation` by amasty. We are using a lot of amasty extensions and they work perfectly fine with a good respond time on issues.

https://amasty.com/customer-segmentation-for-magento-2.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwp-X0BRAFEiwAheRuiwQuIEo4a9LgWQhd1KBmM4Z-jSI6iQY1HlMgdL-j-GGp_FG7Llm8xRoCUvgQAvD_BwE

It may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other solution you are looking for is GeoIp redirect which can be achieved ref (https://github.com/magepal/magento2-geoip) or find other sources in github.

With different storeView or website you can achieve multi-language, separate order number, separate pricing rules, cms content.

The thing is what your requirement is; as mentioned above.