# Change Customer group during checkout based on country

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, customer-group

i want to change customer group on one-page checkout based on checkout address .

Basically two type of customer group : **Indian Customer** , **Outside India**, if checkout country is other than India customer groups should auto switch to **Outside India**

issue : can same be applied for guest customer (non logged in users also).

I am using tier price for products based on Customer Group.

Please help me with way to do same .

Comment: I think you should change your customer flow. Because run time it might be difficult to change the customer group and apply the correct tier price.

Comment: @Nits : i want this thing is it possible that way auto switch store based on country 
:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310183/switch-magento-store-if-country-changes?noredirect=1#comment446153_310183

Answer (score 0):

Use event :-
**here is event : etc/frontend/events.xml**
  "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {        

//Get order details
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); <br>
$guestCustomer = $order->getCustomerIsGuest(); <br>
$groupId  = $order->getCustomerGroupId(); <br>
$order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
```

Check for the country id and then inject customer class

private $customerRepository;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
     CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
{
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

{      

    $id = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customerid=$order->getCustomerId()
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerid);
```

//Set customer to the group id as per requirement
        $customer->setGroupId($group_id);

> > Change code as per requirement , basically this is the logic.

Comment: can customer group be set for guest user